# Question on the proof of the following theorem : the image of a compact set under a continuous function is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

**Theorem :**  Let $f: S \rightarrow T$ be a function from one metric space $(S,d_s)$ to an another metric space $(T,d_t)$. If $f$ is continuous on a compact subset $X$ of $S$, then the image $f(X)$ is a compact subset of $T$.

**Proof:**
The following theorem has been used :

**Theorem 1:** Let $f : S \rightarrow T$ be a function from one metric space $(S,d_s)$ to another $  (T,d_t)$. Then, $f$ is continuous on $S \iff$ **for every open set $Y$ in $T$,** the inverse image $f^{-1}(Y)$ is open in $S$.

Now, let $F$ be an open covering of $f(X)$, so that $f(X) \subseteq \bigcup _{A \in F} A. $

Since, $f$ is  continuous on the metric space $(X,d_s)$, we  can apply theorem $1$ to conclude that each set $f^{-1}A$ is open in $(X,d_s)$

The sets $f^{-1}(A)$ form an open covering of $X$ and since $X$ is compact, a finite number of them cover $X$, say $X \subseteq f^{-1}(A_1) \cup \cdots \cup f^{-1}(A_p) $ and hence, $f(X) \subseteq A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_p$

> **Query** : We took $F = \{ A_1,A_2,\cdots\}$ to be an open covering of $f(X)$. However, in some coverings, it is possible that one of the open sets $A_i \supseteq T$ or $A_i$ does not belong entirely to $T$.
>
> In such a case, we would not be able to apply **theorem $1$** because it requires every open set to be in $T$, whereas it is possible for an open set to be a super set to $T$ or to not belong entirely to $T$ as well.
>
> How does the proof remove this possible anomaly?

Thank you for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is implied by the definition of "open covering" that the sets $A_i$ are subsets of $T$.

Formally, one might define:

If $T$ is a metric space (or topological space) and $E$ is a subset of $T$, then an open covering of $E$ is a set $\{A_i\}$ of open subsets of $T$ such that $\bigcup_i A_i \supset E$.

Comment: The definition goes like this in my book : A collection $F$ of open sets is said to be an open covering of a given set $S$ if $ S \subseteq \bigcup _{A \in F} A$ . It is apparent that $A \in F$ but does the definition guarantee that $ A \subseteq S$ also?

Comment: @VHP: No, the sets $A$ do not have to be subsets of $S$.  But they are implicitly understood to be subsets of the space $T$ in which we are working.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible that there exists an open set $A$ in the collection $F$ such that $A$ does not entirely belong to $T$?

Comment: @VHP: No. Again, the sets $A$ are assumed to be subsets of $T$.

Comment: But, what if , for compactness, there does not exist any collection of subsets $\{A_1,A_2, \cdots \}$ such that each $A_i$ is a subset of $T$? I mean, how can we be sure that there surely exists a collection $F$ such that each $A_i \in F$ must necessarily be a subset of $T$?

Comment: @ Nate .. corrected a sentence above : " such that each $A_i$ is a subset of $T$? "

Comment: If any of the sets $A_i$ is equal to $T$ (which is an open subset of itself), then you get an open cover of any subset of $T$.

Comment: ooo yeah, that sounds good :-)

Comment: @ Nate.. , Thank you very much.